# JavaScript Submit HTML Form via POST

Tags: php, javascript, html, database, forms

I have the following Javascript code:

```
function checkIfValid(){
    var form = document.createuserform;

    if(form.fName.value == "" || form.lName.value == "" || form.pass.value == "" || !isValidEmail()){
    alert("Please Ensure All Fields Are Filled In Correctly");
    }else{
    //submit form
    form.submit();
    }
}

function isValidEmail(){
    var x=document.forms["createuserform"]["email"].value
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
    {
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This for a create user page. The javascript checks to see if the data entered is valid and then submits the form to a php app which then stores the data in the database...

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Create User</title>
<script src="http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/js/createuser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Create User</h1>

<p>Please fill in the details below to create a new user account</p>

<form name = "createuserform" action = "http://dev.speechlink.co.uk/David/createuser.php" method = "post">
<p>First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name = "fName" type="text" size="25"></p>

<p>Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name = "lName" type="text" size="25"></p>

<p>E-mail:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name = "email" type="text" size="25"></p>

<p>Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name = "pass" type="text" size="25"></p>

<p> Gender:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" checked> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="F"> Female</p>

<p>User Type: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="usertype"> 
<option>Athlete</option>
<option>Support Staff</option>
</select></p>

<p><input type ="button" value="Create Account" name = "createuser" onclick="checkIfValid()"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The php code is as follows:

```
<?php

session_start();

$dbh = connect();

//connect to database
function connect() {
  $dbh = mysql_connect ("localhost", "abc123", "def567") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("PDS", $dbh); 
  return $dbh;
}

//insert into database
if (isset($_POST['createuser'])){

    //prevent SQL injections (this version of php does not support mysqli functions)
    $fn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fName']);
    $ln = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lName']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
    $usertype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usertype']);
    if($usertype == 'Athlete'){
      $usertype = 'Athletes';
    }else{
      $usertype = 'SupportStaff';
    }
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

    if(eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)) {

        $query= "SELECT * FROM $usertype WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1 || !mysql_num_rows($result)) {

            $query= "INSERT INTO $usertype (fName, lName, gender, email, password) VALUES ('$fn', '$ln', '$gender', '$email', '$pass')";
            mysql_query($query);
            mysql_close($dbh);
            echo ("&result=true&");         
        } else {
            mysql_close($dbh);
            echo "&result=userexists&";         
        }
    }
    else {
        mysql_close($dbh);
        echo "&result=false&"; //invalid e-mail address
    }   
}
?>
```

The php works when I use a submit button in the HTML form to POST directly to it. But when I use the javascript, the page is targeted but it is blank...nothing is echo'd...Any ideas?

I have a feeling the form is not catching the 'createuser' name of the HTML button firing the javascript...As my php file expects $_POST['createuser'] to be set...perhaps it isn't...?

Comment: You can use FF addons like HTTPFox to see exactly WHAT is being sent to the browser. If the JS is mungeing the form somehow, you'd see it there.

Comment: Some general comments: `alert` boxes are annoying if they are used to display validation results, `ereg*` functions are deprecated in favour of `preg_*` functions. Your database layer should be abstracted. `mysql_close()` is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't press the button with the name "createuser", "createuser" is not part of the data sent to the server.

So instead of checking for "createuser", you should insert a hidden field in your form and check for this.

Answer (score 0):

What stands out to me as the problem is the following:

this should have return false

```
<input type ="button" value="Create Account" name = "createuser" onclick="checkIfValid();return false"></p>
```

this should also return false:

```
function checkIfValid(){
    var form = document.createuserform;

    if(form.fName.value == "" || form.lName.value == "" || form.pass.value == "" || !isValidEmail()){
        alert("Please Ensure All Fields Are Filled In Correctly");
        return false; 
    }else{
        //submit form
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

My thoughts are that its not passing validation, but it is still submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any JS errors in the console?

If no, try this code for validation function

```
function checkIfValid(){
    var form = document.createuserform;
    if(form.fName.value == "" || form.lName.value == "" || form.pass.value == "" || !isValidEmail()){
    alert("Please Ensure All Fields Are Filled In Correctly");
        return false;
    }else{
    //submit form
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this code for your button

```
<input type ="submit" value="Create Account" name = "createuser" onclick="return checkIfValid();" />
```